# Different results with PCA and SVD on data with same units

Tags: normalization, pca, svd, eigenvalue, standardized

At the beginning, i had 400,000 images that were normalized (gray value increase). After that i did a DFT of each picture and got data of 400000 samples with 3200 absolute fourier-coefficients.

Now I would like to do a PCA and SVD. **Since my data is already normalized and all values have the same units**, I thought that I could use the "raw data" for the calculation.
However, the eigenvalues of PCA and the singular values of SVD are different. (show image/link)

What am I doing wrong? How should the data be available for PCA and SVD? normalized,standardized, raw?

Please help me! Thank you

My Code:

```
# samples 400000x3200
# SVD
U,S,VT = svd(samples, full_matrices=False) 

tot_S = sum(S)
var_exp_S = [(i / tot_S) for i in S]
cum_var_exp_S = np.cumsum(var_exp_S)

# PCA
cov_mat = np.cov(samples.T)
eigen_vals, eigen_vecs = np.linalg.eig(cov_mat)
eigen_vals = np.asarray(sorted(eigen_vals,reverse=True))

tot = sum(eigen_vals)
var_exp = [(i / tot) for i in eigen_vals]
cum_var_exp = np.cumsum(var_exp)


num= 3200
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
plt.subplot(121)
plt.title('PCA')
plt.step(range(1,num+1),cum_var_exp[:num], where='mid',color='r')
plt.ylabel('share of variance')
plt.xlabel('principal components')
plt.legend()
plt.grid()

plt.subplot(122)
plt.title('SVD')
plt.step(range(1,num+1),cum_var_exp_S[:num], where='mid',color='r')
plt.ylabel('share of variance')
plt.xlabel('principal components')
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
```

Comment: the normalisation for the pca is done by cov(). numerical problems could be in issue.
i would suggest to use some simple data from wikipedia or similar to validate your the type variables. (i dont remember the dependency between svd and pca since in my library I use power iteration instead of svd)

Comment: First, thank you very much for your answer. I found a dependency for the svd function i'm using in my code: " the corresponding (possibly non-zero) eigenvalues are given by s**2." So regarding to your answer i don't need cov() because the data is already normalized? Then i can calculate the eigenvalues directly with the "raw data" by np.linalg.eigh((samples.T).dot(samples) ?

Comment: no, i guess you need the SVD. I just do it witou because i dont want to implement the svd by myself. 
For the normalisation, the question is probably what you mean. there are some parts in PCA which do some normalisation.
I put it into an answer...:

Answer (score 1):

There are some "normalisations" within a PCA.
Here the code from my own PCA library:

```
//normalize to center
centred = center( samples );
//normalize to square matrix
matrix = cov( centred );
//eigenvalue decomposition
vectors = evd( matrix );
//get normalized eigenvectors:
eigenvectors = get_eigenvectors( vectors );
//get eigenvalues:
eigenvalues = get_eigenvalues( vectors );
```

The [relation between SVD and PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Ky_Fan_norms) is described as: The eigenvalues of M*M are the squares of the singular values of M.

Comment: So i should use PCA/SVD with the raw data?

Comment: that depends on what you want to do with it. PCA normally does an SVD to get the results. what s your plan for the singular values? (I never used them before.)

Comment: Ok i try to explain it with an example in an seperate answer...

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import svd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

X_train = np.asarray([[13.71,1.86,2.36,16.6],[12.22,1.29,1.94,19],
       [13.27,4.28,2.26,20],[13.16,3.57,2.15,21],
       [13.86,1.51,2.67,25]])

#PCA
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train_std = sc.fit_transform(X_train)

cov_mat = np.cov(X_train_std.T)
eigen_vals, eigen_vecs = np.linalg.eigh(cov_mat)
eigen_vals = np.asarray(sorted(eigen_vals, reverse=True))

#SVD
U,eigen_vals_S,V = svd(X_train)
eigen_vals_S2 = (eigen_vals_S**2)

print('\nEigenvalues \n%s' % eigen_vals)
print('\nS \n%s' %eigen_vals_S)
print('\nS**2 \n%s' %eigen_vals_S2)re
```

Output (Eigenvalues and S**2 are different):

Eigenvalues 
[2.79331043 1.28393579 0.90313734 0.01961644]

S 
[55.02775284  3.37434634  2.52347705  0.28664958]

S**2 
[3.02805358e+03 1.13862132e+01 6.36793643e+00 8.21679822e-02]

**now with same results:**

```
#Same eigenvalues
eigen_vals, eigen_vecs = np.linalg.eigh((X_train.T).dot(X_train))
eigen_vals = np.asarray(sorted(eigen_vals, reverse=True))

#SVD
U,eigen_vals_S,V = svd(X_train)
eigen_vals_S2 = (eigen_vals_S**2)

print('\nEigenvalues \n%s' % eigen_vals)
print('\nS \n%s' %eigen_vals_S)
print('\nS**2 \n%s' %eigen_vals_S2)
```

Output:

Eigenvalues 
[3.02805358e+03 1.13862132e+01 6.36793643e+00 8.21679822e-02]

S 
[55.02775284  3.37434634  2.52347705  0.28664958]

S**2 
[3.02805358e+03 1.13862132e+01 6.36793643e+00 8.21679822e-02]

And thats what i don't understand. The way with standardization and cov() is the method for PCA. But as you can see, there are different results, depending on how i calculate the eigenvalues....

Am i wrong with something or why is this so?

Comment: the svd returns singular values, not eigenvalues. as described in my answer, they are related but not equal

Comment: I know, but with the description of svd, which says "In both cases the corresponding (possibly non-zero) eigenvalues are given by s**2." [link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.svd.html) it should be the same, when i square the singular values...or not?

Comment: as far as i understood, it is:
eigenvalue_i( PCA( M * M ) ) == singular_value_i( M )^2

Comment: if you just want to verfiy the eigenvalues , there are other ways. i always reconstruct the samples with the scores of the pca which shows numerical problems.

Comment: But the way i did it "manually" with standardization and cov() is PCA, isn't it?

Comment: i would say so. for me, pca is some normalisation of data, building the matrix (using cov), and finally the tricky eigenvalue-decomposition. the eigenvalue-decomposition is normally implemented using svd, as far as i know. from the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, you calculate the pca-scores.

Comment: in the first code snipped, you got the eigenvalues from cov( train ). in the second one from ( train.T ).dot( train ) - thats why you get different results.

Comment: exactly that is the point i don't understand. For PCA everyone says, that you have to calcuate the covariance matrix: Cov(Train) = 1/(N-1)*(Train.T)*(Train) and then get the eigenvalues of this covariance matrix. But when i compute the eigenvalues "directly" with Train.T*Train, then the results are the same like with SVD and the square of singular values. So the problem is, why take the covariance matrix?

Comment: actually, you do the PCA to get the eigenVECTORS.

Comment: That's true. Nevertheless I was wondering about this issue. Especially if you look at the explanation from amoeba here [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134282/relationship-between-svd-and-pca-how-to-use-svd-to-perform-pca)

Comment: (but the eigenvalues are interesting because they represent the weight of a vector)

Comment: so after the pca, you take the eigenvectors with the biggest eigenvalues, for exameple for feature extraction or compression.

Comment: if your only interest is the eigenvalues, you dont need a full pca of course.

Comment: Yeah so my idea for choosing the number of eigenvectors is a cumulative distribution of eigenvalues/singular values. Of course there is a difference in the distribution of both, but   how i choose the right number of eigenvektors (see my answer with images..)

Comment: the right number depends completely on what you want to do. at the beginning, choose about 80% of the cumulative value. then you take lets say 60% and 95% and you compare performance and quality of the result. if you have a real time application like lets say snap filter for video stream or google page rank, performance is more important. if the application is not time critical, you go for a higher cumulative value.

Comment: You're welcome. I have to thanks for your help and i think i found out the problem with cov() and PCA here [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/301549/how-to-obtain-covariance-matrix-eigenvalues-from-singular-values?noredirect=1&lq=1). I've centered my data and calculated the cov matrix from scratch and with the answer from amoeba i know now that eigenvalues == (singularvalues**2)/(N-1). That's it. So from now on, i've never trust again just on the functions, better calculate by myself :)

Answer (score 0):

These images are from the dataset (400000x3200):

[PCA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXnFx.png)

[SVD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDLO6.png)